# reverse an array with recursion

Tags: c, xcode

When I try to run this it asks me to input 11 numbers instead of 10 with is really weird then it out puts like an even weirder result please help.

```
void function(int array[],int length,int start)
{
    if (length<start)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp=array[start];
    array[start]=array[length];
    array[length]=temp;
    function(array,length-1,start+1);
}

int main()
{
    int array[10],num=0,num2=10;
    printf("enter the array:\n");
    for (int i =0; i<num2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&array[i]);
    }
    function(array,num2,num);
    for (int t = 0; t<num2; t++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[t]);
    }
}
```

then this is the out put for the array 1,2 ... 10,11

```
enter the array:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

return
214696143
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
(lldb)
```

please help

Comment: Perhaps change `num2=10;` to `num2=9;` so you do not go out of bounds in the array

Comment: I didn't really understand that can you please be more specific keep in mind we fixed the input so now it runs with 10 numbers fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last index of an array with size 10 is actually 9. So this line:

```
function(array,num2,num);
```

Should be:

```
function(array,num2-1,num);
```

Also, your use of `scanf` is incorrect. Eliminate the `\n` character. Read more about `scanf` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

I corrected your code and tested it here: https://onlinegdb.com/B1Yy4yBqN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int array[],int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
      int temp;
      temp = array[start];
      array[start] = array[end];
      array[end] = temp;
      function(array, start+1, end-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[10],num=0,num2=10;
    printf("enter the array:\n");
    for (int i =0; i<num2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    function(array,num,num2 - 1);
    for (int t = 0; t<num2; t++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[t]);
    }
}
```

Note that in C, the array starts from 0. The last index is 9 not 10. You need to access to the last element using `length - 1` instead of `length`

Comment: thank you it did fix the input so now it runs with 10 numbers with is great but the program its self still seems to have a bag. I am now getting this instead.                                                    enter the array:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
270860496
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
(lldb)

Comment: @ahmedkh Why don't you try it before posting? https://www.onlinegdb.com/ gives me the output of 10,8,6... for the input of ..7,8,9,10.

Comment: @ahmedkh You should mention that you did the edit in your posting to correct the mistake of `function(array,length-2,start+1);` it is now `function(array,length-1,start+1);`

Comment: @ЯрославМашко Edited. I was focusing in the 9 vs 10 issue I didn't care a lot what the program does. my bad!

Comment: @yadinmeretzki try it now

Comment: The parameter name `length` is misleading. It is really the index of the final element, so `end` would be better.

Comment: What is the `if (array == NULL)` `return;` part of `function` for? It seems redundant.

Comment: sorry guys I sould have mentioned that I am only allowed to use 1 function to do it and also I didn't really understand what you meant in you last comment @lan Abbott

Comment: and also how do I edit my original post and code I uploaded

Comment: and also why would array ever be equal to null

Comment: and the main problem now is the weird number it spits out in the first number it tries to print after the reverse.